# Display the percentage of an downloaded file with comma

Tags: java, file, download

i want to check my downloadspeed in an application and for that i will download a 1GB zip file from a server. i cant figure out how to get a number like 12,4% or 45,8% with comma. the exact filesize is 222331664 bytes

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SpeedTest
{
    private static Logger log;
    private static URL fileToDownload;

    public static void main(String argc[]) throws Exception {
        log = new Logger("SpeedTest");

        // http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.15/linux-headers-2.6.15-020615_2.6.15-020615_all.deb
        fileToDownload = new URL("http://www.specialservice.ml/1GB.zip");

        log.logToLogger("Lade " + fileToDownload);

        long totalDownload = 0; // total bytes downloaded
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // size of the buffer
        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // buffer
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileToDownload.openStream());
        int dataRead = 0; // data read in each try
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); // starting time of download

        while ((dataRead = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
            totalDownload += dataRead; // adding data downloaded to total data
            float tempPercentage = (totalDownload * 100) / 222331664;
            log.logToLogger("lade " + dataRead + " Bytes -> " + String.format("%.2f", tempPercentage) + "% geladen"); 
        }

        /* download rate in bytes per second */
        float bytesPerSec = totalDownload / ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000);
        log.logToLogger(bytesPerSec + " Bps");

        /* download rate in kilobytes per second */
        float kbPerSec = bytesPerSec / (1024);
        log.logToLogger(kbPerSec + " KBps ");

        /* download rate in megabytes per second */
        float mbPerSec = kbPerSec / (1024);
        log.logToLogger(mbPerSec + " MBps ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `222331664` literal a `float`

```
float tempPercentage = (totalDownload * 100) / 222331664f;
```

And to format it use:

```
String.format("%.1f", tempPercentage).replace(".", ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
     log.logToLogger("lade " + dataRead + " Bytes -> " + ´df.format(tempPercentage) + "% geladen");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format, for example:

```
String.format("%.2f", tempPercentage);
```

Comment: i tried but its always 1,00% - 2,00% - 3,00% and never 1,2% or 3,4%

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to round your float to 1 decimal after the comma? If that is the case, try this:

```
float tempPercentage = (totalDownload * 100) / 222331664;
String roundedPercentage = String.format("%.1f, tempPercentage);
log.logToLogger("lade " + dataRead + " Bytes -> " + roundedPercentage + "% geladen");
```

The `1` in `%.1f` is how many decimals you want after the comma, so if you later decide you want 2 decimals after the comma instead, just change this `%.2f`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) if you need more flexible format.